# How to call PUT query with headers in retrofit android

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit

I want to update the parse table field. I have tested my API call via postman, its work fine on "PUT". It does not work on "GET" and "POST" query, so kindly give me answer only for "PUT".

I have an url, 3 headers and 1 field value which I want to update.

I used the REST API of retroFit and volley for calling "PUT" but I did not get desire result.

Can anyone tell me the solution that how to call "PUT" method in retroFit and volley?

//Khawaja Qasim

This is my code which I have used.

```
@Headers({
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "X-Parse-Application-Id: TestApp",
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 1234567890"
        })
        @PUT("https://example.com/hello")
        void updateValue(@Body JSONObject lastMessage,
                         Callback<JsonElement> callback);

..............

 ApiClient.getClient().updateValue(new JSONObject(hashMapKey), new BaseCallback() {
```

Answer (score 0):

used hader tag when calling function parameter these is current syntex

Authorization is key which we send header tag in post man
@POST("cart/update")
    Call getCartUpdate(@Header("Authorization") String Authorization, @Header("Time") String time, @Header("Key") String Key, @Body ProductList productList);

Comment: thanks for reply.
But I want to ask what about "PUT" method? You gave the answer of "POST" method.

Comment: i am not sure  but try  this .


@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("/question/new")

void send(
    @Field("questionName") String questionName,
    @Field("questionType") String questionType,choice
   @Header("X-Parse-Application-Id") String X-Parse-Application-Id,
   @Header("X-Parse-REST-API-Key) String X-Parse-REST-API-Key,
    @Field("correctOptionIndex") int correctOptionIndex,
    Callback<RestResponse<LoginResponseBody>> callback
 );

Answer (score 0):

**Define Custom Request Headers**

Retrofit provides two options to define HTTP request header fields: static and dynamic. Static headers can’t be changed for different requests. The header’s key and value are fixed and initiated with the app startup.

In contrast, dynamic headers must be set for each request.

**Static Request Header**
The first option to add a static header is to define the header and respective value for your API method as an annotation. The header gets automatically added by Retrofit for every request using this method. The annotation can be either key-value-pair as one string or as a list of strings. Let's face two specific examples which illustrate the definition options:

**Retrofit 2**

```
public interface UserService {  
    @Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=640000")
    @GET("/tasks")
    Call<List<Task>> getTasks();
}
```

**Retrofit 1.9**

```
public interface UserService {  
    @Headers("Cache-Control: max-age=640000")
    @GET("/tasks")
    List<Task> getTasks();
}
```

For more reference.  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Comment: Thanks for reply. but I have put the header. and want to execute "PUT" method.
You gave the answer of "GET" method.